# How to get an child value from Firebase in android studio

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

**I Want to find this Click here to see the photo**

[image]

How should i find the child value which i have marked in the image.

Comment: What did you try already? If nothing, then I highly recommend reading the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/), and taking the [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/);

Answer (score 0):

that's a user id,you can use`getUid()` to get that but as said in earlier comment share a snippet of your code for clarification as your question is quite ambigous.
To get a child `FirebaseDatbase.getInstance().getReference("Patient").child(Uid)`